# About the latest technologies in Riverpod

Tags: flutter, dart, provider, riverpod

I recently started learning Flutter. So when I asked a question about Riverpod on this site, I received the following advice:

> The literature is rushing to catch up with Remi's prolific development. In brief, avoid legacy ChangeNotifier, StateNotifier (and their providers) and StateProvider. Use only Provider, FutureProvider, StreamProvider, and Notifier, AsyncNotifier, StreamNotifier (and their providers).
> (I appreciate the person who gave me advice. Thank you.)

And here is the code that is causing the issue:

```
final sampleProvider = StateNotifierProvider<SampleNotifier, int>((ref) {
  return SampleNotifier();
});

class SampleNotifier extends StateNotifier<int> {
  SampleNotifier() : super(0);
  void setDay({required int day}) {
    state = day;
  }
}
```

I don't understand the issue you were advised about. Could you please provide more details about what needs to be changed in the code and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you can use `Notifier` and `NotifierProvider`:

```dart
final sampleProvider = NotifierProvider<SampleNotifier, int>(() {
  return SampleNotifier();
});

class SampleNotifier extends Notifier<int> {

  @override
  int build() {
    // Load initial value
    // it is also safe to use `ref.watch` here
    return 0;
  }

  void setDay({required int day}) {
    // use here `ref.read` when necessary
    state = day;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. It was helpful. I will refer to it.

Comment: When I actually try the code, I encounter the error message: "The argument type 'SampleNotifier Function(dynamic)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'SampleNotifier Function()'."

Comment: After the fix.


`final sampleProvider = NotifierProvider<SampleNotifier, int>(() {
  return SampleNotifier();
});`

Comment: Yes, out of habit I forgot to remove `ref`. Corrected

Comment: And based on design, you can use `SampleNotifier.new` in place of `() => SampleNotifier()`.  It's much easier to read.  This is using a "constructor tearoff", a handy feature.